# Cannot access site with IIS - Error when choosing .NET Framework 4 in Application Pool

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I am trying to configure a site to run locally on a windows 10 machine.

This is a .NET 4.0 site. When I launch the site using .NET 2.0 in the application pool for the site, I get the following error:

[image]

When I try to run changing the application pool to .NET 4.0 (classic) I just get a 404 error.

Am I missing some configuration or changes somewhere?

This is the log I see from IIS:

```
2019-12-16 09:48:12 127.0.0.1 GET / - 443 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/78.0.3904.108+Safari/537.36 - 404 17 50 6
2019-12-16 09:56:31 127.0.0.1 GET / - 443 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/78.0.3904.108+Safari/537.36 - 500 0 0 708
2019-12-16 09:58:36 127.0.0.1 GET / - 443 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/78.0.3904.108+Safari/537.36 - 404 17 50 4
2019-12-16 09:59:15 127.0.0.1 GET / - 443 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/78.0.3904.108+Safari/537.36 - 404 17 50 1
```

Error 500 when I access using .NET 2.0, 404 when I access through .NET 4.0.

Also, is there somewhere I can see detailed logs of what is causing this, where IIS is looking for the file?

Comment: Why do you need classic pipeline mode? What happens if you use a .NET 4.x pool with integrated pipeline?

Comment: @LexLi same thing happens. nonetheless, I have been able to get past that error, will leave solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to get past this error, even though I am still facing others.

In case anyone stumbles upon this, what was missing was the HTTP Activation windows feature.

I am leaving an image here, even though it's in portuguese:

[image]